# How to avoid duplicate entries in access from vb6?

Tags: ms-access, vb6, primary-key, duplicates

I am using Vb6 and Access 2007. I am adding records to the access table name "subjectcode" from vb6. The details of subjectcode table are below.

Subjectcode table :         Heading(Degree,Branch,Year1,Year2,Semester,Subjectcode,Subjectname,Theory_Practical, Major_Allied_Elective) values (Bsc,computerscience,2001,2004,1,RACS1,Vb6 programming,Theory,Major)

Note :The primary key in the above table is Degree,Branch,Year1,Year2,Semester,Subjectcode
And the code i used to add entry to the access table from vb6 are given below :

```
    If degree = "" Or branch1 = "" Or year1 = "" Or year2 = "" Or semester = "" Or subcode.Text = "" Or subname.Text = "" Or theory.Text = "" Or major.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox "Fields can't be empty ! All are mandatory!"
    Else
    rs.Open "select * from subjectcode", con, 1, 3
    rs.AddNew
    rs!degree = degree
    rs!branch = branch1
    rs!year1 = year1
    rs!year2 = year2
    rs!semester = semester
    rs!Subjectcode = subcode.Text
    rs!Subjectname = subname.Text
    rs!Theory_Practical = theory.Text
    rs!Major_Allied_Elective = major.Text
    rs.Update
    MsgBox "Successfully Saved !", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "info"
    rs.Close
    End If
```

And the screenshot of that Add form of vb6 is here: http://tinypic.com/r/w7c7if/6
The record is added when the same entry is not exist. And if the record is already exist it should say "Record Already exists" and i don't know how to do that. Could you guys give me idea please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a save method to save your record, and a method to query the database and check for an existing record before you save the data.

```
Public Sub SaveSubjectCode(ByVal vDegree As String, ByVal vBranch As String, ByVal vYear1 As Integer, ByVal vYear2 As Integer, ByVal vSemester As Integer, ByVal Subjectcode...)

    If (DoesRecordExist(vDegree, vBranch, vYear1, vYear2, vSemester, vSubjectcode) = True Then
        ' Warn the user
        MessageBox("I'm sorry Dave I can't do that. The record already exists.")
    Else
        ' Save the record
    End If

End Sub

Private Function DoesRecordExist(ByVal vDegree as String, ByVal vBranch As String, ByVal vYear1 As Integer, ByVal vYear2 As Long, ByVal vSemester As Integer, ByVal vSubjectcode As String) As Boolean

    RecordSet = query 'Query the database for the existing record
    If RecordSet.BOF And RecordSet.EOF Then
        DoesRecordExist = False
    Else
        DoesRecordExist = True
    End If

End Function
```

Also, you want to avoid the the Select * query that selects every record unless you really need it because it is likely to be slow, and get slower as the number of records grow. If you want to get a recordset just to use to add a new record you can include a Where clause that does not return any records `"select * from subjectcode WHERE 1 = 2, con, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic`

Comment: Thank you so much Beaner friend... Yes sure friend i will avoid select * query n again thanks friend :)

Answer (score 2):

When you create a field in a table you specify whether duplicates are allowed or not.  Then an offending add or update raises an exception.

The SQL DML looks like:

```
ALTER TABLE tblCustomers
    ADD CONSTRAINT CustomerNames UNIQUE
    ([Last Name], [First Name])
```

And there are other powerful features such as check contraints as well:

```
ALTER TABLE tblInvoices
    ADD CONSTRAINT CheckAmount
    CHECK (Amount > 0)
```

One advantage of constraints is that your database's integrity is not held hostage by rogue applications that may fail to do chatty pre-qualification queries (or fail to implement them properly).  Another is the performance improvement over chatty techniques and the fact that when there are multiple updaters the database can change between pre-qual query and update.

Comment: I use this method as well on SQL databases, but was unsure if Access supported it. I still use the query method when checking for duplicates though, so I avoid having to translate DB errors, and if I need to I can give the user feedback about the existing record.

Comment: Thank you Bob friend for the reply.It also worked and again thank you so much friend !

Comment: Sometimes these things are situational.  For example one database might allow dups on a field, but *not* for a certain program or a certain activity.  So they both have their place though I think "probe-then-post" is dicey unless you use proper locking.